# Include Controller in TYPO3 Sitepackage Builder

Tags: typo3

I'm still relatively new to TYPO3 development. I have created a TYPO3 site package with [www.sitepackagebuilder.com](http://www.sitepackagebuilder.com) and would like to integrate a controller there.
At the moment the research leads me again and again to the Extension Builder.
Is there an easy way to insert the controller?
Your support would help me a lot.

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a Controller can have different targets:

1. Serving a Plugin for the Frontend
2. Serving a Module for the Backend

While the manual implementation isn't too hard, the extension_builder is nevertheless easing the steps and can also be seen as good example, even if manual adjustments are desired.
I'd suggest making a simple test / example extension with Frontend Plugin, to see the most common usage.
Another test-extension with a backend module would show clearly the differences.

Naturally it's possible to make one extension with many plugins and modules, but for beginners that's confusing and the differences for backend and frontend are not so easy to spot in comparison to simple extensions.

**Creating an example extension**

If you want to create test / example extensions, care about the naming, it will make things much easier:

- chose a typical vendor that can be easily spotted (and adjusted later perhaps)
- chose an extension key with underscores. While it's advised in some documentation to avoid those eventually, it's much easier to understand naming conventions intuitively. Also it's easier to transfer some settings if single parts of namespace, names for plugin(s) and module(s) as well as classes are typical. While it's possible to create an extension "test" with a plugin "test", it's more advisable to chose "my_test_extension" as extension key and "mytestplugin" as plugin key (as extension_builder never allows underscores in the key for plugins). Both will be "translated" then to "MyTestExtension" and "Mytestplugin".
- chose some data model(s) that are also typical and different than extension- or pluginname. As proposition you could add a model "MyMainModel" and one "MySubModel", you can create a relation then and it will be easier to spot where which class belongs too and which controller shall handle which model. As model properties you can create some common fields like "title" as input field ('String' in extension_builder) and "description" ('Rich Text*' in extension_builder) as text field. If you know you need a special field later, add it, then you get the example code directly too and just can copy it to your sitepackage later.
- For Model names use always singular. This is more or less standard  and makes things much easier. For single relation fields plural might be fitting to their functionality if several relations can be created, that should be the only case where plural is chosen.

Bear in mind that you might have to adjust some things perhaps, especially namespaces and table-names including the label-names in language files. Nevertheless the above mentioned advises will make this much easier.
If names are not clearly related to a special part of the extension, it's very likely that names will be adjusted wrong and this can be a nightmare to repair for people who never know the details very well.

In the extension builder click always on the option "Show advanced options" in the corner top right:

[image]

This is how the settings look like in the extension_builder

[image]

Now a plugin has to be created.
First we still adjust a few things in the models

[image]

[image]

and now the plugin can be configured:

[image]

After saving the extension, the first interesting part concerning the plugin respectively the controllers is what is written in the file ext_localconf.php:

[image]

You can see that the controller names are based on the model names. Usually the first controller of this list that can satisfy a request is taken, so MyMainModelController is the default controller.

In the controllers the interesting part might be the namespace, but it can be seen above in the file ext_localconf already too:

[image]

The next interesting part is what's written in the TypoScript setup:

[image]

and which tables are created (default fields are not listed here):

[image]

Still one look in the model class MyMainModel concerning the relation:

[image]

Important is that due to the 1:n relation there isn't only set- and get-method but also add- and remove method.

Ok, so the extension is in a state that could be transferred to a sitepackage and now we create a git-repository.
As repository name I could use just the extension key, which would be perfectly fine and in general possible concerning git, composer and also packagist. Nevertheless, on packagist it's quite common that no underscores are used but instead common minus' as hyphens.
Therefore as repository name I choose "my-test-extension".
This is btw. also what is used in the file composer.json:

[image]

The common commands to add all files to a repository are usually mentioned when a repository is created on a git-platform like github.com or gitlab.com. You can commit and push the new repository and access the files online then.
You can find the repository I created for this walk-thru on https://github.com/DavidBruchmann/my-test-extension.
And if you find the extension [mytestvendor/my-test-extension](https://packagist.org/packages/mytestvendor/my-test-extension) on packagist, that's the same.

Feel welcome to link your repositories in the comments, perhaps also including a module for the backend.

Answer (score 2):

The Extensionbuilder is just a tool to build complete extensions.

But of cause you can extract individual aspects from an example extension you generate with the Extensionbuilder.

On the other hand you can read the [documentation for extension development](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Index.html) which [files](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FileStructure/Index.html) belong to an extension and which content they hold.